Why Multiline MDTextField, dosen't change size heigth?
I'm trying to make a multi-line outlined MDtextField, with specific height but it doesn't change.
MDBoxLayout:

    orientation: 'vertical'
    md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.backgroundColor
    adaptive_height:True
    MDTextField:
        id: name
        mode: "outlined"
        size_hint_x: None
        width: dp(400)
        size_hint_y:None
        height:dp(40)

        MDTextFieldHintText:
            text:"type name "

        MDTextFieldHelperText:
                        
        MDTextFieldMaxLengthText:
            max_text_length: 30
    
    MDTextField:
        id: description
        multiline: True
        mode: "outlined"
        size_hint_x: None
        width: dp(400)
        size_hint_y:None
        height:dp(40)

        MDTextFieldHintText:
            text: "Type description here"

        MDTextFieldHelperText:
            
        MDTextFieldMaxLengthText:
            max_text_length: 200

I expect that both the textboxes have the same size before starting typing. And also, the hint text move with the border, instead the hint stay inside the multi-line box.
